# Converting string to date format (yyyy/MM/dd) in JAVA

Tags: java, date, sql-update, simpledateformat

I am facing an issue when I convert my string to date format.

This is what I have tried -

First try:

```
        String completionDate1 = request.getParameter("completion_date");
        System.out.println(completionDate1); // O/P --> 21/10/2016 (Correct)
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
        Date date = new Date();
        date = df.parse(completionDate1);
        System.out.println(date); // O/P --> Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 27 (Inorrect)
```

Second try:

```
        String completionDate1 = request.getParameter("completion_date");
        System.out.println(completionDate1); // O/P --> 21/10/2016 (Correct)
        Date completionDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(completionDate1);
        System.out.println(completionDate); // O/P --> Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 27 (Inorrect)
```

The output I'm expecting is that, the `completionDate` should be `Date` format not `String`. I'm just printing the completionDate just to make sure the date format is getting getting converted.

The main intention of getting it in date format is I need this for an Update query so it has to be Date and not String.

Kindly let me know where I'm going wrong. I need this date format as I need to store this date in a database.

Thanks

Comment: you print a `Date` object. What it does print is determined by the `Date#toString` method and not by the format you created previously. If you want to print it formated reuse the format to get the propper format in `String` representation.

Comment: @KevinEsche This is the exception I get when I try to update my table using that date - Data truncation: Incorrect date value: ' Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 IST 27 ' for column 'completion_date' at row 1

Comment: @zombie It's not a duplicate, that is converting current date to string, my question is String to Date and change in format as well.

Comment: @Shashi Kiran The issue is same as you are also facing problem while converting Date to String.

Comment: @ShashiKiran A `Date` object does not have a format, it's just a number of millis since the epoch. Its `toString` method has a user-friendly output but you can't change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to format the date after parsing it but your parsing format is also incorrect so its giving wrong output. Try

```
 String completionDate1 = "21/10/2016";
 System.out.println(completionDate1);
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 Date date = new Date();
 date = df.parse(completionDate1);
 DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
 System.out.println(df1.format(date));
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/FpFbVZ)

Comment: I need the completionDate to be in date format, so should I parse it again ?
Is this the right way?

Comment: Yes you have to parse String date to Date date to format it because [`DateFormat#format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) takes Date type as argument

Answer (score 1):

## Wrong pattern

First problem is that your defined parsing pattern does not match your input string. For `21/10/2016` pattern should be `dd/MM/yyyy`.

## java.sql.Date versus java.util.Date

Second problem is that for database access you should be using the [`java.sql.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) class for a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. Not to be confused with [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) which is a date *and* time-of-day value. You should specify the fully-qualified class name in such discussions as this Question.

Neither of these classes have a “format”. They have their own internal representation, a count from [epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

## java.time

Third problem is that you are using old outdated classes. In Java 8 and later, use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework now built-in. In Java 6 & 7, use its back-port, the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. For Android, use the adaptation of that back-port, ThreeTenABP.

In the java.time classes we now have the `LocalDate` class for date-only values.

```
String input = "21/10/2016"
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy" );
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse( input , formatter );
```

Hopefully some day JDBC drivers will be updated to directly use the java.time types. Until then, use the new methods added to the old java.sql types to convert.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = java.sql.Date.valueOf( localDate );
```

Now pass that `java.sql.Date` object to the `setDate` method on a `PreparedStatement` object for transmission to a database.

Note that at no time did we make use of any more strings. We went from original input `String` to `java.time.Date` to `java.sql.Date`.

At no point did we use `java.util.Date`. Check your `import` statements to eliminate `java.util.Date`.

By the way, to go the other direction from `java.sql.Date` to `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate localDate = mySqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
String completionDate = df.format(request.getParameter("completion_date"));
System.out.println(completionDate);
```

Comment: I need the completionDate to be in date format, so should I parse it again ?
Is this the right way?

Comment: No you don't need to parse it. You simply need to format your completionDate. If you take a look at your first try. The output is *21/10/2016* so in my example your request compeletion_date parameter gets formatted to the given format

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
 String completionDate1 = request.getParameter("completion_date");
 System.out.println(completionDate1); // O/P --> 21/10/2016 (Correct)
 Date completionDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(completionDate1);

 String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(completionDate);
 System.out.println(date);
```

Comment: I need the completionDate to be in date format, so should I parse it again ?
Is this the right way?